# RestKit app is crashing with [NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingQueryParameters:]: unrecognized selector message

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, restkit

I am new in RestKit i am using RKObjectMapping to call service but its crashing, Error Log is

```
2012-07-20 18:31:58.319 SampleRest[6589:207] -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingQueryParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d74c20
```

and here is my code which i written :

```
-(void) callService {
RKObjectMapping *rk = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[vo class]];
[rk mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"primaryKey"];
[rk mapKeyPath:@"opposing_team_name" toAttribute:@"opp_team_name"];
RKObjectManager *rkManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString: @"http://hercules.softwaytechnologies.com/sportsapp_v3.0"];
[rkManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/event_games/get?application_id=1" delegate:self];
```

}

Please help, am i doing any mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For installation  i followed this link : https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

Comment: This question comes up quite frequently. It is a problem with your linker flags. You need to have -all_load and -ObjC otherwise the categories are not linked and you get this crash.

Comment: For me, per the hint in the documentation `Try removing the -all_load flag if you are receiving runtime errors related to selectors not being found`, I was getting the above error and removing the `-all_load` flag resolved my issue.

Comment: you may use force_load flag if you still need to force load on a some frameworks

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and have found that the process of adding **RestKit** is painful and therefore confusing.
I noticed that the linker flag `-ObjC`, although I know I set it, was no longer applied to my target!
Once I set other linker flags to `-ObjC -all_load` all was well.

**So what I suggest is double check and double check again with this!**

The other areas I've had issues with is where to add the source files for **RestKit** physically. I don't follow the instructions to add it as a sub of my repo because I'm using `Mercurial` and found it all just messed up.
Eventually I find that copying the whole contents of the original `RestKit` folder into the base folder holding my solution works.
I all seems a bit messy - although when you drop the `RestKit` proj file into `xCode` it all appears neatly arranged in its folders.
*(If someone could suggest a better way of doing this -which works!!- I'd like to know, thanks)*